# beamer: position section head in a fixed position

Tags: beamer, sectioning

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
      \Large\insertsectionhead\par%                                                                                                                                                                         
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vfill
  \end{frame}
  }

\AtBeginSubsection[]{
  \begin{frame}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
      \Large\insertsectionhead\par%                                                                                                                                                                         
      \vspace{0.5cm}
      \large\insertsubsectionhead\par%                                                                                                                                                                      
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vfill
  \end{frame}
  }
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1 A}
\end{document}
```

I use `\vspace` with the intention to fix the positions of section and subsection heads. However, when viewed in a slide mode, the section head is changing position when moving from section title page to subsection title page.

How to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that  by default the frame content is vertically centered and needs to be aligned to the top. This can be achieved by mean of the `[t]` option given globally as in `\documentclass[t]{beamer}` or individually for a particular frame as in `\begin{frame}[t]`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
      \Large\insertsectionhead\par%                                                                                                                                                                         
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    %\vfill
  \end{frame}
  }

\AtBeginSubsection[]{
  \begin{frame} % or  \begin{frame}[t] (if not set globally)
    \vspace{3cm}
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
      \Large\insertsectionhead\par%                                                                                                                                                                         
      \vspace{0.5cm}
      \large\insertsubsectionhead\par%                                                                                                                                                                      
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    %\vfill
  \end{frame}
  }
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1 A}
\end{document}
```